# The paramiko do not enter the configure mode

Tags: python, paramiko

My router device have `cli mode` and `configure mode`, in the `cli mode` can use the `edit` command enter the `configure mode`.

The paramiko do not enter the configure mode.

```
import paramiko
import sys
import subprocess
#
# we instantiate a new object referencing paramiko's SSHClient class
#
vm = paramiko.SSHClient()
vm.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
vm.connect('13.193.240.45', username='root', password='my_pwd')
#
vmtransport = vm.get_transport()
dest_addr = ('13.57.109.2', 22) #edited#
local_addr = ('13.193.240.45', 22) #edited#
vmchannel = vmtransport.open_channel("direct-tcpip", dest_addr, local_addr)
#
jhost = paramiko.SSHClient()
jhost.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
#jhost.load_host_keys('/home/osmanl/.ssh/known_hosts') #disabled#
jhost.connect('13.57.109.2', username='admin', password='pwd', sock=vmchannel)
#
stdin1, stdout1, stderr1 = jhost.exec_command('edit') # there should enter the configure mode.
print(stdout1.read())
print(stderr1.read())

stdin2, stdout2, stderr2 = jhost.exec_command("set interfaces ae16 unit 200 family inet address 1.1.1.14/29")  # this command is only can be execute in the configure mode, but in there will report error. there only can execute the `cli mode commands`
#print (stdin2, stdout2.read(), stderr2)
print(stdout2.read())
print(stderr2.read())

stdin, stdout, stderr = jhost.exec_command('commit')

#
#print (stdin, stdout.read(), stderr) 
#
jhost.close()
vm.close()
```

Why the `paramiko` can not enter the configure mode of my router?

My router model is `Juniper MX480`.

---

Summary:

I want to executed the command(`edit`) to enter the configure mode, but seems the paramiko context did not do that(did not enter the configure mode), so I can not execute the configure mode commands.

I mean:
The router have cli mode , configuration mode, when I execute the edit should enter the configuration mode, then execute the commands of `configuration mode, but I use paramiko execute the edit`, still only can execute the cli mode commands.

---

**EDIT-01**

The cli mode:

```
{master}                                                                        
JD@HK-MX-RE0>
```

the configure mode:

```
{master}[edit]                                                                  
jd@HK-MX-RE0#
```

When I execute `edit` or `configure private` to enter the configure mode:

```
jd@HK-MX-RE0> configure private                                             
warning: uncommitted changes will be discarded on exit                          
Entering configuration mode                                                     

{master}[edit]                                                                  
jd@HK-MX-RE0#
```

Comment: What does "do not enter the configuration mode" mean? Do you get an error message? Which one? What behavior do you observ?

Comment: The router have cli mode , configuration mode, when I execute the `edit` should enter the configuration mode, then execute the commands of ` configuration mode`, but I use paramiko execute the `edit`, still only can execute the cli mode commands.

Comment: The error is just the `error: unknown command: xxx`, it means the command can not execute in the router cli mode.

Comment: OK, you should add that to your question.